# check txt one by one with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

what i'm trying to do is check div value one by one via jquery and php, if php is say value is 1 to make the div value color red if its 0 to make the txt color blue, the check script is not working right if i put on php q1 = Tag1 is not making that div red color ...

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="Tags_Data">
 <div class="TagID_1">Tag1</div>
 <div class="TagID_1_Status"></div>
 <div class="TagID_2">Tag2</div>
 <div class="TagID_2_Status"></div>
 <div class="TagID_3">Tag3</div>
 <div class="TagID_3_Status"></div>
 <div class="TagID_4">Tag4</div>
 <div class="TagID_4_Status"></div>
 <div class="TagID_5">Tag5</div>
 <div class="TagID_5_Status"></div>
 <div class="TagID_6">Tag6</div>
 <div class="TagID_6_Status"></div>
</div>
```

This is my jquery script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var delay = 200;
  $("div[class*='TagID_']").each(function() {
   $(this).hide().delay(delay).fadeIn(1850);
   delay += 200;

   var Tag_ID             = $(this).attr("class");
   var ID_Split           = Tag_ID.split('_');
   var Tag_Data_ID        = ID_Split[2];

   var Tag_Scan           = $('.TagID_' + Tag_Data_ID);


// ----------------- Post Tag And Check It
   $.post("tags_check.php", { q1 : Tag_Scan.attr("value") },

// ----------------- Get The Result
   function(result) {
    if(result == 1) {
     Tag_Scan.css('color','red');
    } else {
     Tag_Scan.css('color','blue');
    }
   });

  });
 });
```

This is my PHP Code on tags_check.php:

```
<?php
 if($_GET["q1"] == "Tag3") {
  echo 1;
 } else {
  echo 0;
 }
?>
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/3C2Pa/1/

**Update:**
i update the script http://jsfiddle.net/3C2Pa/3 but still the checking is not working ... hope someone can help me with this

Comment: In the fiddle you have `Box_ID.split('_');`

Comment: yes i correct now the script sorry about that

Comment: why do you use class instead of id?

Comment: i think the problem is here: Tag_Scan.attr("value")  you have to use Tag_Scan.text()

Comment: You have several redundant pieces of your code.  For example `Tag_Scan` is equal to `$(this)` every odd time.  Also `Tag_Scan.attr("value")` makes no sense, considering `TagScan` will never have a value attribute in your  provided code.  Also, you're making twice the number of server request as you need to (n times as many as you should, where n is the number of requests you make).

Comment: i update the script http://jsfiddle.net/3C2Pa/3/ but still the checking is not working ... hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got three errors in your code:

First one:

```
var Tag_Data_ID        = ID_Split[2];
```

arrays start from zero as index. So you'll find what you get in the position 1.

```
var Tag_Data_ID        = ID_Split[1];
```

Second one:

```
Tag_Scan.attr("value")
```

you have to use

```
Tag_Scan.text();
```

Third one:

you are using "post" to call your php script but you are reading vals through "GET". Use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`

Moreover I suggest that you use `id` and `class` in a better way :)